# Print all pages that contain absolute elements

Tags: html, firefox, layout, printing, mozilla

[source code](https://7fb55b1445ab6f0d96cf31fe9c6cd27dd21ab1cd.googledrive.com/host/0B4ZQO92LSOT4ektVYk5NMFZ6QU0/fish.htm)

style

```
.page{
position:relative;
right:0mm;
height:279mm;
margin:0;
border:1px solid black;
}

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

html

```
<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>


<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>


<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>


<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>


<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>


<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>


<div class="page">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
     </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
      some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`    
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px ">
          some `DIV` with `position:absolute;top;right`
    </div>
</div>
```

size of page is A4 Paper.

While the show all page in firefox but 
in print preview show only fist page of 7 page?

in ie and chrome print preview is correct!

Is this problem has realative to  [Splitting Absolutely positioned frames not implemented - Missing second page of content when printing or print previewing this site](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154892)?

Comment: if i am not wrong?? you want to print pages that contain absolute elements?? why?? is there a specific reason??

Comment: yes, i should set every div in special position with special top and right

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this, it may not be the proper answer. butt it will help you in right direction

Link

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

**For normal use**

```
.page{
position:relative;
right:0mm;
height:279mm;
margin:0;
border:1px solid black;
}

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

**For print purpose**

we always create different CSS

**only display what's needed**

you can overide the css properties with **!important**

```
@media only print
{
    body * { display: none !important; }
    body:after { content: "Don't waste paper!"; }
.page{ position:relative!important;; right:0mm; height:279mm; margin:0; border:1px solid black;}
}
```

**`set every div in special position with special top and right`**

sorry to say that you cant do it in print.

if you some how how added also it will affect in other parts like header, footer, inconsistent tables likewise.

my suggestion is that make a standard top, right, and position. so that page will look neeat and clean.

Comment: in print preview show this error;`dont waste paper!`

Comment: what you mean?? in print preview show this error;dont waste paper!

Comment: you mean you want the message in print as **"dont waste paper"** ryt?? if is it yes i will create a page for you.

Comment: i am not getting what you are asking?? i saw your source code.it looks like you have messed up with the html inline styles. i suggest you have to remove all and style through css properly.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/ it can help you further